# Credit Card masking

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, devexpress

How do I mask `textedit` with this following image ?

[image]

How do I simplify the `IIN RANGES` because for MasterCard type I need to type it one by one

```
`[*5]{1}[*1-5]{1}[*0-9]{2}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{4,5}`
```

1. But what if `Maestro`cardType ? Is there a format that isn't explicitly explained one by one as above and also as you know there's a lot of [creditcard](https://baymard.com/checkout-usability/credit-card-patterns)
2. Do I need to make a lot of `if` for each type of credit card for masking in the `text edit`. So when in combobox, if I choose a specific credit card, it would use the `masking` type for that credit card

Answer (score 0):

1. He does something like this:
   https://github.com/jondavidjohn/payform/blob/master/src/payform.coffee

> ```
> type: 'mastercard'
> pattern: /^(5[1-5]|2[2-7])/
> length: [16]
>
> type: 'visaelectron'
> pattern: /^4(026|17500|405|508|844|91[37])/
> length: [16]
>
> type: 'forbrugsforeningen'
> pattern: /^600/
> length: [16]
> ```

2. This or in a XML file.

> ```
> Dictionary<string, Card> cards = new Dictionary<string, Card>();
> cards.Add("VISA",new Card(4, "[5-6]"));
> cards.Add("MAESTRO",new Card(5, "[5-6]"));
> cards.Add("FORB",new Card(4, "[5-6]"));
>
> class Card
> {
>     public Card(int length, string format){
>         //TODO
>     }
>     public int Length;
>     public string format;
> }
> ```